# Javascript Regular Expression blacklist combinations for social security number validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple social security number regex `^\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{2}[- ]?\d{4}$`

I'd like to blacklist some combinations of numbers for each of the three groups of numbers. Specifically I'd like to accomplish the following 3 conditions.

1. First 3 digits cannot be 000, 666 or larger than 899
2. 4th and 5th digits cannot be 00
3. Last 4 digits cannot be 0000

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!ssn.match(/^((000|666|9\d{2})-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{3}-00-\d{4}|\d{3}-\d{2}-0{4})$/)) {
  ...
}
```

where `ssn` is a string containing the SSN.

This regex works in 3 parts, each of which corresponds to your conditions.

1. `(000|666|9\d{2})-\d{2}-\d{4}` matches any SSN starting with `000`, `666`, or `9XX`
2. `\d{3}-00-\d{4}` matches any SSN with `00` in the middle
3. `\d{3}-\d{2}-0{4}` matches any SSN with `0000` in the end

The `^` in the beginning and `$` at the end force an exact match of `ssn`.  You can omit these if you're searching as a substring.

The `(` and `)` grouping operators in conjunction with `|` allow for any of the `|` separated options to match.

If a SSN doesn't match any of these three, then it passes your conditions

Answer (score 0):

[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34010408/4554883) is pretty right, but the RegEx itself could be way more simplier:

```
/^(?:000|666|9\d\d)|^\d{3}-?00|0{4}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good regex [here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=ssn&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

`/^(?!000)(?!666)(?!9)\d{3}([- ]?)(?!00)\d{2}\1(?!0000)\d{4}$/`